# How can i store Promise instead of Deferred

Tags: javascript, promise, deferred

I have a piece of code, which communicate with iOS native layer by dispatching request with callback ID, and storing `Deferred` in array. Then when the callback comes, we can resolve or reject this `Deferred`.

My code:

```
jsGate = (function () {
    function jsGate() {}
    jsGate._messageCount = 0;
    jsGate._callbackDeferreds = {};
    jsGate.dispatch = function (plugin, method, args) {
        var callbackID, d, message;
        callbackID = this._messageCount;
        message = {
            plugin: plugin,
            method: method,
            "arguments": args,
            callbackID: callbackID
        };
        send(message)
        this._messageCount++;
        d = new Deferred;
        this._callbackDeferreds[callbackID] = d;
        return d.promise;
    };

    jsGate.callBack = function (callbackID, isSuccess, valueOrReason) {
        var d;
        d = this._callbackDeferreds[callbackID];
        if (isSuccess) {
            d.resolve(valueOrReason[0]);
        } else {
            d.reject(valueOrReason[0]);
        }
        return delete this._callbackDeferreds[callbackID];
    };

    return jsGate;
})();
```

Examples of usage:

```
jsGate.dispatch("ReadLater", "fetchSomething", []).then(function (value) {
    return console.log(value);
});
return jsGate.dispatch("ReadLater", "asyncError", []).then(function (value) {
    return console.log(value);
}, function (reason) {
    return console.log("Failed: " + reason);
});
```

What's the best practice for that using A+ Promises?

Comment: Why are you storing it in `_callbackDeferreds`?

Comment: I'm trying to provide two-way communication between iOS WKWebView and JS, and iOS can support only one-way communication ('send'). iOS is later doing `eval` with callbackID to emulate two-way comm. 
Swift code for callback is `bridge.vc.webView.evaluateJavaScript("Goldengate.callBack(\(callbackID), \(success), \(Goldengate.toJSON([reasonOrValue])))", completionHandler: nil)`
whole Swift file is here: https://github.com/radex/Goldengate/blob/master/Goldengate/GoldengateVC.swift

Comment: Nolan Lawson suggested revealing constructor approach, described [here](https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/). I'll check that out

Comment: I don't think there's any way round it - you have to store Deferreds or something Deferred-like with resolve and reject methods. The overall pattern could be tidied up but that's about all.

Comment: But if `send()` is yours to modify, that's a different matter entirely. You could pass it a callback function instead of a callbackID, or even better, have it return a promise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 it's not. Whole problem is because it's non-modifable and it can't return anything at all.

Comment: Mmm, back to plan-A then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research: there's no clean way of doing this without strange hacks. The main difference between `Deferred` and `Promise` is that we can't manipulate the `Promise` result from outside. In general - it's good approach, but in this specific case, we need that functionality, so - we have to stick with `Deferred`.